# dojo.tooltipdialog cancel(X) button missing

Tags: dojo

dojo tool tip dialog:
how to put cancelbutton(X) in dojo.tooltip dialog.
I am unable to put that X in that dialog

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem that there is a cancel button for the "dijit.TooltipDialog". What you can possibly  do is, add a x (cancel button) in the content of the tip dialog and attach onclick event to it.

You may have a global variable 'dialog' and add the cancel button in its content and attach onclick TooltipDIalog hide event to it as follows.

```
        var dialog = new dijit.TooltipDialog({
        content: '<p> whatever you want to display</p><br />' + '<a href="#" onclick="dijit.popup.close(dialog);return false;">x</a>'
    });
```

Or attach an onclick event to the link after the TooltipDialog dom is added to the document as follows.

```
var dialog = new dijit.TooltipDialog({
                                   content: '<p> whatever you want to display</p><br />' + '<a id="close-dialog" href="#">x</a>',
                                   onShow : function () {
                                     dojo.connect (dojo.byId('close-dialog'), "onclick", function (evt) {
                                                     dojo.stopEvent(evt);
                                                     dijit.popup.close(dialog);
                                                   });
                                   }
                                 });
```